# Need help in using R "as." function

Tags: r

```
a <- x
```

where `x` is data frame with 120 columns in it.

```
sum(a$column1) == 0
```

this condition works fine.

I have a situation where I have to find each column’s sum.

So created vector `m` with list of all column names in it

```
m <- colnames(a)
```

tried calling the vector values inside the sum function it is throwing error.

```
sum(m[1]) == 0
```

throws some error. Not sure which `as.` Function to use here.

Comment: `help("colSums")`, `"help("Extract")`

Comment: I edited your question because the line where you extracted the column names did not make much sense. You should copy paste the error in your question.

Comment: As suggested by @Roland , and if I understood your question correctly, `colSums(x)` should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

is `sapply(x, sum)` what you want?